# Squashing git commits made before and after a merge from main

Tags: git

Let’s say, I have the following state of my repository. Is it possible to squash commits #1 and #3 knowing for sure that there is not any conflict in changes? How?

[Graphical visualization of the situation at hand.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpOhF.png)

Detailed description:
Initially, there was just a branch “main”. Then my colleague created a branch “iss” and pushed it to the remote repository. I continued working on the same topic and added a new commit (but not pushed it yet). Then, after some time, I wanted to continue, but part of the files I wanted to work on became obsolete due to the ongoing development in “main”. So I merged “main” into “iss” to get the new changes there resulting in a merge commit (again still local). Then I made a one (or even a few) new local commits into the “iss” branch. At this time I am ready to push the changes to the server, but I realize, some of my commits could be squashed together (or let's say all of them) to keep the history clean.

An optional follow up question would be: Is there any better recommended workflow for this kind of situation when new changes arrive into “main” before I am finished with my work in “iss”?

I am new to Git and I recently encountered the following usage pattern, which I believe must be quite frequent when cooperating with someone else on the same project. Still, I did not find any discussion on how to treat it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the graph you drew:

```
git checkout -B iss origin/iss
git cherry-pick -n --first-parent --no-merges @..iss@{1}
git commit
git merge origin/main
```

That squashes all the non-merge iss commits into one and then redoes the merge. To arbitrarily distribute the accumulated history into multiple commits you can instead of the one commit for everything do `git reset` and a series of commits with `git add -p` to pick which hunks go in which rebuilt commit.

The old commits' messages are still in your repo, if for instance you don't want to retype existing messages you can `git commit -c oldcommithash`.

Answer (score 0):

When new changes are arrived to main branch you can [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) your branch on the main, you will not have merge commits then. Anyway, you can rebase a branch with merge commits and they will gone. And the most powerful feature is interactive rebase (`rebase -i`) where you can squash, fixup, reorder commits interactively

Comment: From my point of view, the problem here is that first commit of the "iss" branch (the one has origin/iss next to it) was already pushed to the remote repository. Isn't this preventing me from rebasing? 

When I tried `rebase -i` in the situation depicted above to reorder and squash my commits, the changes from "main" were also once again registered as if they taken place also on the "iss" branch, which I think is not desirable.

Comment: Rebase takes your commits and apply them on top of main branch, so your commits are possible to merge without merge commits. It will rewrite only your branch history, main branch will remain unchanged, so nothing prevents you from rewrite your temporary branch

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best solution I came up with consists of the following sequence of steps:

1. soft reset to "my commit #2"
2. stash
3. hard reset to "my commit #1"
4. soft reset to "origin/iss"
5. stash
6. merge main to iss
7. stash apply
8. new commit